# Grafana / InfluxDB : $interval data point count and query math

Tags: influxdb, grafana

Is there a way for `Grafana` and `InfluxDB` to tell me how many data points I have put in one Grafana $interval? And to use this in query math?

For example, to make a query:

```
"SELECT (count("value") / $number_of_data_points_in_interval) FROM...GROUP BY time($interval)" etc.?
```

background:

I'm writing an `InfluxDB` query in `Grafana`:

```
SELECT count("value") FROM "cpu_value" WHERE "type_instance" = 'idle' AND value < 0.5 AND $timeFilter GROUP BY time($interval) fill(null)
```

My goal is to display how many cpu cores are over 99.5% in use at any point in time, but the problem is that as Grafana changes the $interval depending on zoom level, the values for my query start to get very big-- far larger than the number of cores on my machine.

The simple solution would be to divide the count that the query returns by the number of data points put in each $interval, so the result will scale to the number of cores I have.